# How do I get a month calendar view with appointment list?

Tags: 8.0, calendars

<sup>[the "good" ones in "How can I do X?" questions](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12/1140)</sup>

It seems I cannot get the calendar on my WP8 phone<sup>Lumia 620</sup> to display an overview of the month with a list of the appointments for the selected day **on the same screen as the month view**.

What I want would be something like on symbian devices:
[image]

Note that in the area below the month view (where the img shows "(Tap to create entry)") any appointments for the selected days would be shown. On the same screen as the month overview.

Switching to another day will keep the month view in the upper area of the screen and only switch the lower area to the appointments of the selected day.

With the WP8 calendar, tapping a day will open the day view (only the day) and then I don't have the month view anymore to quickly switch to another day of this month.

What do I need to get this to work on WP8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this is not currently possible with the built-in calendar application.

I am unaffiliated with this app, but [Calendar[+]](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/calendar/83b8e400-6f66-4e1f-a143-99009185dac3) appears to have a similar function as well as [Chronos Calendar](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/chronos-calendar/18aae83d-c70c-4ac1-8bf6-c6e726e031df). I just installed this app on my phone, and it does exactly what you described.

Here's a screenshot of how Calendar[+] looks:

[image: image of Calendar[+] showing month and day details]

Here's a screenshot of how Chronos Calendar looks:

[image: image of Chronos Calendar showing month and day details]

Comment: And it's free too. How very nice. (Disclaimer: Haven't tried it myself yet.)